# Iterate through ComboBoxes in a GridViewColumn

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

EDIT: After posting I realized I made a simple error in my binding.  Solved.

I have a GridViewColumn defined by the following XAML:

```
...
               <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=extensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  Width="105" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedExtension, Mode=TwoWay}">
                           <ComboBox.Resources>
                              <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>
                           </ComboBox.Resources>
                        </ComboBox>
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
...
```

At any rate, making the SelectedItem binding function properly is not working.  Is it possible to iterate through the ComboBoxes and just manually set the SelectedItem?

Comment: what do you mean SelectedItem binding is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: @MiklósBalogh After putting this up I realized I messed my SelectedItem binding up.  Thanks.

Comment: Turn on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx to possibly get a binding error.  Is set of get called on selectedExtension?

Comment: @MiklósBalogh Just out of curiosity, how _do_ I iterate through my ComboBoxes?  Even though SelectedItem now works, I still want to go through and selectively modify the IsEditable (or VerticalScrollBarWidthKey, etc) on each ComboBox?  Thanks.